# Home folders are appearing on the desktop

Tags: symbolic-link, desktop-icons, troubleshooting

Every time I login to Ubuntu, I see all the Home folders: Documents, Downloads, Videos, Music, etc. are all appearing on the desktop with red cross mark. It is not a shortcut, if I delete them on the desktop, the actual folder is also getting deleted. Once I delete them on the desktop and try to open the folder inside Home folder, it showing an error "Too many levels of symbolic links." Please let me know, how to fix it.

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy[image]

Comment: Can you provide more details like which OS version, the screenshot of the folders, etc??

Comment: Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy